# how to return one object from array of object mongodb

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongoose, mongodb-query, database

```
var customerData = Customers.findOne(
   {'phone': phone}, 
   { 'restaurants': { $elemMatch: { 'restaurantId': Meteor.userId() } } }
);
```

I am using `$elemMatch` to return only one object from `Restaurants` array,
but still it is returning all the objects of array.WHY?

---

Is their any other way of returning only one object?

Comment: First parameter is for query, second is for projection (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/#db.collection.findOne). Your query should look like: `Customers.findOne({'phone':phone, 'restaurants.restaurantId' : Meteor.userId()});`

Answer (score 0):

```
var customerData = Customers.findOne(  
{'phone': phone`,'restaurants.restaurantId':Meteor.userId()`}).restaurants;
```

It must be the viable solution

Thanks